# How to add product flavor to version name in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a Android Gradle project that has multiple flavors like so.

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        apple {
            applicationId "com.myapp.apple"
        }

        orange {
            applicationId "com.myapp.orange"
        }

        banana {
            applicationId "com.myapp.banana"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In my `build.gradle` I also have the following piece of code that sets the `versionName` to either **0.8-dev** if it's an local build or **0.8-123** if it's a Jenkin's build.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        // Get the build number from Jenkins, otherwise use 'dev'
        ext.buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "dev"
        versionName "0.8-$buildNumber"
        ...
    }
}
```

Since I now have different flavors of the same project, I'd like to prefix the `versionName` with the flavor so it looks something like this **apple-0.8-dev** or **orange-0.8-dev**, depending on which flavor is built.

How do I go about doing this?

I've tried using `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` but I can't access that in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Re-define the `versionName` in your flavors:

```
def version="0.8"

android {
    defaultConfig {
      versionName version
    }
    ...
    productFlavors {
        apple {
            applicationId "com.myapp.apple"
            versionName "apple-$version"
        }

        orange {
            applicationId "com.myapp.orange"
            versionName "orange-$version"
        }

        banana {
            applicationId "com.myapp.banana"
            versionName "banana-$version"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. I needed to also move the `ext.buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "dev"` above `defaultConfig{...}` so that I could access its value in `productFlavors{...}

Comment: CommonsWare Is there any way to extract "-0.8" and then past it as value to version name? Every time I publish new version I release two types of build, so I'd to have version number as "singleton" for all version names

Comment: @murt: See the edited answer. Groovy double-quoted strings support string interpolation for `$` "macros". I show defining the version as a simple constant value, but you could define it in `gradle.properties`, in a custom `.properties` file, obtain it from a build server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of Android Studio, it can be done through dialog from the top menu:

> File > Project Structure >

[image]